# usb: why my f_uvc doesn't answer GET_DEF request?

Tags: device, uvc

I need to implement uvc1.5 spec in my device, I choose  linux3.4 as my kernel, and I want to use the `drivers/usb/gadget/webcam.c` 
    as my function driver. But it doesn't function properly.

According to the signals captured by wireshark, when the host sends the `GET_DEF` request to the device, my device answer `-ENOENT` which results in a failure to the enumeration.

I find out that when the `composite.c` receives this kind of requests, it will forward them to `f->set_up` to continue.

The main part of `f->set_up` is:

```
    uvc->event_setup_out = !(ctrl->bRequestType & USB_DIR_IN);
    uvc->event_length = le16_to_cpu(ctrl->wLength);

    memset(&v4l2_event, 0, sizeof(v4l2_event));
    v4l2_event.type = UVC_EVENT_SETUP;
    memcpy(&uvc_event->req, ctrl, sizeof(uvc_event->req));
    v4l2_event_queue(&uvc->vdev, &v4l2_event);
```

The call of `v4l2_event_queue` is what puzzles me: who will handle this event?
    I didn't see any code doing such event related initialization work.....

And my question is how to handle this event properly, so I can answer the `GET_DEF` request ?

Answer (score -2):

It's a V4L2 event you should deal with in another place. You can receive v4l2 event through

```
rt = ioctl(dev->fd, VIDIOC_DQEVENT,&v4l2_event);
```

Then you can parse this v4l2_event, it maybe GET_CUR, GER_LEN,etc. So you can response those requests by yourself define.